# Sharepoint database and Tables

Tags: database, sharepoint

I had created a multi choice column called "technology" on our SharePoint portal.
Recently, by mistake I clicked on delete button while making changes to the column value and now I want to restore the system in the original form.
I have recreated the column with all the options, the problem is that all the documents had the technology value associated to them.
I now have the task of attaching the technology name to every document.

I would like to know what database table will the information be where I can go and add the correct value so that it shows up on the list.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really do it through the database, you are better off creating a powershell script to run through the documents, adding the correct value.

Other wise you will have to "Edit in datasheet" to get any fast updating of the values.

Comment: If you want to do anything in the database you will lose your Microsoft support on SharePoint.